# How do I split a string into an array of characters with Swift?

Tags: ios, mobile, swift

I am new to iOS programming with Swift.
I have stored a string in the variable `stringlength.`

Let's say...

> `var stringlength = "Hello"`

How do I split this to an array of characters?

```
Example: ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
```

In Java I know that `toCharArray()` works but what do I do in Swift? I have looked everywhere online.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: worse come to worse you can use a for loop?